Techniques for uplift modelling/Conditional Average Treatment Effect(CATE) estimation for observational data
I have very recently started learning CI and was going through this very famous paper:https://proceedings.mlr.press/v67/gutierrez17a.html which mentions that Randomised Control Trials are an essential part of uplift modelling.
My problem is the following: a company runs a WhatsApp marketting campaign where they send the message to only those customers who are most likely (high probability) to onboard to one of their services.
This probability is computed using an ML model. We are trying to propose that we do not send the message to users who will do so without any such nudge and that will reduce the cost of acquisition.
This will require estimating CATE for each customer and sending the message only to those with high CATE estimates. I couldn't find any established techniques that are used for  estimating CATE in observational data.
All I found regarding CATE estimation on observational data was this: https://youtu.be/0GK6IZut6K8?si=Ha1klt_kQaCILyGO but they don't cite any paper ( I think). The causal ml library by uber also mentions that they support CATE estimation from observational data but I don't see any examples.
It would be great if someone can point me to some papers which have been implemented in the industry.
